# How to check if a file has already been saved using JFilechooser?

Tags: java, jfilechooser, printwriter

I have been working on a text editor and I have created a menu that will allow you to save a file. I was able to write the required code to save a file, but how would I check if that specific file has already been saved? If it has been saved just save any changes to that same file, but if it has not been saved, save the file with a new name. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have already gone over the java api as well as similar questions that already have been posted on here and nothing seems to work for me. Here is what I have:

```
            JFileChooser saveAsChooser = new JFileChooser();
            saveAsItem.addActionListener(event -> {
            int saveResult = saveAsChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
            File myFile = saveAsChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String fileName = myFile.getName().toString();
            setMyTitle("Swing Text Editor [" + fileName + "]");

            if(saveResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                try {
                PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File(myFile.getName()));
                file.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    });


    JFileChooser saveChooser = new JFileChooser();
    saveItem.addActionListener(event -> {
        int saveResult = saveChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        File myFile = saveAsChooser.getSelectedFile();
        File myFileName = new File(myFile.getName());
        String fileName = myFile.getName().toString();
        setMyTitle("Swing Text Editor [" + fileName + "]");

        if(saveResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            if(myFileName.exists() == false)
            {
                try {
                PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File(myFile.getName()));
                file.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if(saveResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            if(myFileName.exists() == true)
            {
                try {
                PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(myFile.getName());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is what it says when it crashes:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyFrame.lambda$new$3(Editor.java:146)
    at     javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You mean like [`File.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists--)?

Comment: Ouch -- please, no code in comments. If you need to show more code, then please edit your original question so that the code is present and readable. Also, are you asking about this new code? And have you tested it?

Comment: I will change it. No it crashed that's why I was asking.

Comment: I tried that and my program just keeps crashing @James

Comment: Crashing? Then include the stacktrace for the exception in your question.

Comment: It has been added @JamesKPolk

Comment: As with any NPE, the key is to examine the line that throws the exception, here `Editor.java:146`. So which line is this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That would be this line: `File myFileName = new File(myFile.getName());`

Comment: .... and I don't see that line of code above in your code post.

Comment: I apologize, that has been edited already.

Comment: About the NPE you have to check your code as other people already commented. About the OP, you should have 2 buffers, one that have the user changes and one that have the saved version. First time the saved version will be empty, so you just make it the same of the user  changes buffer on first save. Then you could check difference from those buffers before saving.